# X.F WP8.1 Cannot find type System.Windows.Controls.Control in module System.Windows.dll

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, windows-phone-8.1, xamarin.forms

My `Xamarin.Forms` (Windows Phone 8.1) app worked until a couple of days ago, when it started showing me this error:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v14.0\8.1\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Common.targets(327,9):
>       Xaml Internal Error error WMC9999: Cannot find type System.Windows.Controls.Control in module System.Windows.dll.

I found a couple of solutions here and on the web, but none worked for me.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Think I've seen an error similar to this where my XAML was wrong (forgot to close a tag or something like that) on a page however it didn't give me exact details. Instead I double clicked the error and it took me to my page but not to the incorrect XAML. The `targets` is trying to help you locate that I think as in line 327, column 9 or something like that. It was a while ago so can't quite remember how it hung together in my VS. I just remember having to mess around trying to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out it was a "simple" library conflict: a not-working library ([TeeChart](https://components.xamarin.com/view/TeeChartForms), note to future self and any other could stumble upon this issue) I forgot to remove was raising this error. Once removed it, my project compiled.

Comment: That happened to me too. I tried to remove some references to test and it worked...